# How to change position of UITextField while delete below textfiled?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'm new in iPhone development. Now I want to display 40 text field with Horizontal scrolling..

I've already created this `UITextField` using below code.

```
// Create the scrollView:
UIScrollView *scrViewRankTracker = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
[scrViewRankTracker setContentSize: CGSizeMake(1200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:scrViewRankTracker];
scrViewRankTracker.delegate = self;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 150);
[scrViewRankTracker scrollRectToVisible: frame animated:YES];

float x = 10;
float y = 10;
float width = 100;
float height = 30;

// Create the textfield using for loop:

for(int textFieldIndex =0;textFieldIndex<40;textFieldIndex++)
{
    tfRankTracker = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    tfRankTracker.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [tfRankTracker setTag:textFieldIndex+1];
    [tfRankTracker setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [tfRankTracker setDelegate:self];

    [scrViewRankTracker addSubview:tfRankTracker];

    x = x + width + 20;

    if((textFieldIndex+1)%10==0)
    {
        x = 10;
        y = y + height + 20;
    }
}
```

The output of this code will display below
Ex.

```
1     2   3   4   5    6   7   8   9   10

11  12  13  14  15  16  17 18  19  20

21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30

31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

Now, suppose if I delete no.4's text field than no.14 will take a place of no.4...no.24 will take place of no.14 and no.34 will take a place of no 24...

[image]

Can someone help me!!!!!
Thanks

Comment: don't do like that ... Use of collection view and add each text filed in to collection view

Comment: is there any demo code for that?

Comment: plz find the collection view from cocoacontrols.com and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Set tags for all the `UITextField` similar to the sequence you have.. Then..

```
-(void)onDelete:(UITextField *)textField{
    int curTag=textField.tag;

    int tagToReplace=curTag+10;

    UITextField *textFieldToReplace=[self.view viewWithTag:tagToReplace];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
       textFieldToReplace.frame=textField.frame;
    }];

}
```

The above code should do what you need, may need some tweak.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in place of self.view you have to write [scrViewRankTracker.view viewWithTag:tagToReplace] ?

Comment: first i want to identify selected textfield and than clicking on delete button...the selected textfield should be deleted.

Comment: @Sweeta You can have a variable selectedTextField, and use it.. Mine code will definitely work if you understand.

Comment: @Rushabh My code is just and idea how it should work, I have already mentioned it may need some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `collectionViewController` for your problem. This **[tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)** will guide you step by step.